# C# PhantomJS process memory leak and exit while using windows/tabs

Tags: c#, phantomjs

tell me, please, I want to use multiple instances of PhantomJSDriver :

```
PhantomJSDriver[] Driver = new PhantomJSDriver[memberscount];

for (int i = 0; i < memberscount; i++)
{
   driverService[i] = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
   driverService[i].HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
   driverService[i].LoadImages = false;
   driverService[i].ProxyType = "http";
   driverService[i].Proxy = proxy[i];
   options[i] = new PhantomJSOptions();
   options[i].AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36");
   Driver[i] = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService[i], options[i]);
   Driver[i].Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);
   Driver[i].ExecutePhantomJS(script);
 }
```

Each instance works well, until I try to open a new windows/tab and open the link in it :

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jscript = Driver[count] as IJavaScriptExecutor;
jscript.ExecuteScript("window.open('', '_blank');");
Driver[i].SwitchTo().Window(Driver[i].WindowHandles[1]);
Driver[i].Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

At this moment, the Second and all next instances of  **Driver** start loading CPU by 10%, and the RAM grows exponentially, until the *phantomjs.ex*e process closes itself (without errors)

But the first instance of PhantomJSDriver works stably, even with windows, the problems begin only if i open the window with the second and further drivers.

Tried to open like this:

```
Driver.ExecuteJavaScript("window.open('" + url + "', '_blank');");
```

And have the same problem... 
How can I find the reason? Thanks!

**Update** :

Discovered, that this also happens after creation of the second additional window (the third one), and following the link:

```
url = "...1";
Driver[i].ExecuteScript("window.open('', '_blank');");
Driver[i].SwitchTo().Window(Driver[i].WindowHandles[1]);
Driver[i].Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

url = "...2";
Driver[i].ExecuteScript("window.open('', '_blank');");
Driver[i].SwitchTo().Window(Driver[i].WindowHandles[2]);
Driver[i].Navigate().GoToUrl(url); // After that, process crashing
```

CurrentWindowHandle variable is okay, the third window created, but when interacting with it, the process shuts down.